# Add hours to a time datatype in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to add a simple number of hours to the time datatype (time column) or to the datetime datatype (date_time column) in SQL Oracle. The input and expected output are shown below.

```
Date_time (yyyy-mm-dd)          Time     hrs_to_add    Expected_Output
2019-01-01  13:50               13:50    5             18:50
2019-01-03  17:00               17:00    25            18:00
```

In my original table I only have the "Date_time (yyyy-mm-dd)" and the "hrs to add" columns. To create the "Time" column I used

```
TO_CHAR (Date_time , 'HH24:MI:SS')
```

I need some help for creating the expected output column
Thank you

Comment: In Oracle you have neither `time` nor `datetime` data type. What are the data types of these columns?

Answer (score 0):

Use INTERVAL 'X' HOUR, as below:

```
SELECT systimestamp, systimestamp + INTERVAL '2' HOUR FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

As your column `hrs_to_add` has a `number` data type and `Date_time` contains date with time, I would recommend to use:

```
SELECT Date_time  + (hrs_to_add/24) FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Adding 1 into date will add exactly one day and as you need to add hours, we can add (Number of hours/24) in date to get the desired result.

Cheers!!

Comment: I tried adding the number of hours columns to the date_time column, the result is  the same. that is there is no difference in the output. it does not seem to be working.

Comment: Before trying to execute sql, please execute `alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';` then check the result.